# How to replace all newline characters except last character in C-string with something else using C or C++03

Tags: c++, c, string, replace, c++03

Given a C-string (`const char*`), what is an efficient way to replace all newline characters (`'\n'`) except the last character (if it exists) with a different character (say, `'\r'`). Some examples:

```
Original string:  "Hello\nworld %x\n"
Converted string: "Hello\rworld %x\n"

Original string:  "\n"
Converted string: "\n"

Original string:  "\n\nHi%dthere"
Converted string: "\r\rHi%dthere"

Original string:  "\n\n\n"
Converted string: "\r\r\n"

Original string:  "sdasdfasdf"
Converted string: "sdasdfasdf"
```

C or C++ (up to C++03 only) may be used to do the conversion. C++11 or higher versions may not be used.

Comment: Walk the string backwards to find the last newline, then walk from the front to that newline replacing newlines as you go.

Comment: What difficulties have you faced into?

Comment: @BradyDean Backward walk is unnecessary.

Comment: @S.M. Walk the string, do replacements, and maintain a pointer to the last-modified character. After walking assign `\n` through the pointer. There's probably numerous ways to do this.

Comment: @S.M., none really. it's just that i have to perform this operation a lot, so i'd like to know if there is an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Walk the string looking for `'\n'` not followed by `'\0'`.

```
void hc_replace(char* s) {
  while (*s) {
    if (s[0] == '\n' && s[1]) *s = '\r';
    s++;
  }
}
```

OP has "Given a C-string `const char*`.  Will let OP handle the string memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an in-place solution. I don't think you can get any better than O(n).

```
void replace_all_but_last_newline(char* str, char replacement) {
    char* last = NULL;

    for (char* i = str; *i; ++i) {
        if (*i == '\n') {
            *i = replacement;
            last = i;
        }
    }

    if (last) {
        *last = '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function name is excellent. It tells exactly what it does!

Comment: Consider case `"\n\nHi%dthere"`.  I suspect it becomes `"\r\nHi%dthere"` when `"\n\nHi%dthere"` is the goal.

Answer (score 1):

We may use the STL algorithm `std::replace`, first we check if the input string is empty. For nonempty string, we skip the last character, and then we apply `std::replace`, it's an in place change. So if we want to keep the original string, we need to change the argument as a copy other than a mutable reference here.

The function `replace_but_not_last` is c++03. The main function is just for tests only, it's not related to what OP wants, so I use c++17 here.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void replace_but_not_last(std::string& str, char from = '\n', char to = '\r') {
  if (str.empty()) return;

  std::replace(str.begin(), --str.end(), from, to);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> tests = {
      {"Hello\nworld %x\n", "Hello\rworld %x\n"},
      {"", ""},
      {"\n", "\n"},
      {"\n\nHi%dthere", "\r\rHi%dthere"},
      {"\n\n\n", "\r\r\n"},
      {"sdasdfasdf", "sdasdfasdf"}};
  for (auto& [input, expected] : tests) {
    replace_but_not_last(input);
    assert(input == expected);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ruks The function `replace_but_not_last` is c++03, I think. The main function is just for tests only, it's not related to what OP wants, so I use c++17 here.

Answer (score 1):

My participation in the challenge.

```
void replace_all_but_last_newline(char* str, char replacement) {
  for (const char* front = (*str) ? str + 1 : str; *front; ++str, ++front) {
    if (*str == '\n')
      *str = replacement;
  }
}
```